# Pass Data from form 1 to form 2 but redirect form 1 to form 3 using php

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

It may seems strange but I possible don't know how to get it done. To explain it more, here's my dilemma. I have a page which I named form1.php (just for testing) which has an input textbox and an input submit type which is eclosed in a form which will redirect to form4.html (this is HTML).

**Here's the code for form 1**

```
<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Testing of GPS</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
      </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <form action="form4.html" method="POST" name="manualform">
            <div style="border:solid;background:#B29393;height:50%;width:50%;margin-top:150px;">
                <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                Mobile Number:<input type="text" name="platemobnum" id="platemobnum"/>
                <br/><br/>
                From:<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="from" name="from">
                <br/><br/>
                <input type="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
```

Now, I want the value of my data in this form (form1.php) to be posted not it form4.html but in form2.php but the form1.php must redirect to form4.html.

**Here's the form2.php**

```
<?php

try {

    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $sth = $db->query("SELECT * FROM locations where name = '$platemobnum' ");
    $locations = $sth->fetchAll();


} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Here's my form 4**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var map;

    // Ban Jelačić Square - Center of Zagreb, Croatia
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(14.641667, 121.084167);

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    function init() {

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: center,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map, 
            position: center,
        });

         makeRequest('get_locations.php', function(data) {

            var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                displayLocation(data[i]);
            }
        });
         bounds.extend(myLatLng);
        // window.alert(infowindow);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    function makeRequest(url, callback) {
        var request;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        } else {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE6, IE5
        }
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                callback(request);
            }
        }
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.send();
    }




    function displayLocation(location) {

        var content =   '<div class="infoWindow"><strong>'  + location.name + '</strong>'
                        + '<br/>'     + location.address
                        + '<br/>'     + location.description + '</div>';

        if (parseInt(location.lat) == 0) {
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': location.address }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map, 
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        title: location.name
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(content);
                        infowindow.open(map,marker);
                    });
                }

            });
        } else {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.lat), parseFloat(location.lon));
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: position,
                title: location.name
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

        }

    }



    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">

    <h1>LTFRB Monitoring System</h1>

    <section id="sidebar">
        <div id="directions_panel"></div>
    </section>

    <section id="main">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 70%; height: 500px;"></div>
    </section>

</body>
```

Is it possible and Ik would like to thank anyone for your advance help/.

Comment: Could you not make your action="form2.php" and then in form2.php redirect with header('location: form4.php');

Comment: I did but in form 2 it only selects 1 data before redirecting to form 4

Comment: It sounds to me like the problem is in the logic of form2.php rather than in the redirect process.       I presume that form2.php has more code than you have shown, can you show more?

Comment: To make it more clear...Form 1 is some sort of log in page where you got to pick the plate....then form 4 is the index.html which holds the design and the scripts. Form 2 is just a query page and form 4 gets the data from form 2. Ill update my post

Comment: Is form2.php the same as get_locations.php?  If so you don't really need to go through it on the way to form4.html as you are calling it via Ajax within form4.html anyway (but you will need to pass $platemobnum as a parameter in your ajax call) .  

I would look at what get_locations.php is returning, first from the database look up to make sure it is getting the expected records and then from the Ajax call to make sure it is passing back those records in the expected format.

Comment: Im sorry for being so out of this world. But can you guide me on how to do it. :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73350/discussion-between-mark-1-and-dodgeball).

Comment: Figured it out Sir. Many thanks.